# C++ writing to a Binary file with ofstream

Tags: c++, binary, ofstream

For a small file format I'm developing I need to output a header of 519 bytes to a file. I'm a bit new to the whole ofstream concept. Though I have some experience with reading the header of a Truevision Targa file. But output is something I'm far lees familiar with.

So basically, here is my problem.

I opened an instance of ofstream, and I need to output a header like so:

```
typedef struct header {
    char      version;   // offset 0, length 1
    short int width;     // offset 1, length 2
    short int height;    // offset 3, length 2
    short int pathlen;   // offset 5, length 2
    char      desc[512]; // offset 7, length 512
} fileHeader;
```

Now I need to get all of this in the first 519 bytes of a file, the rest of the content varies, how would I go around copying this header into my file?

I preferably want to do this using the ofstream class, but I'm also fine with the original C library. I've been at this for 2 hours now, and I've not gotten anywhere yet and trying to search on Google doesn't help much either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& out, const header& myheader) {
    out.write((char*)&myheader.version, sizeof(myheader.version));
    out.write((char*)&myheader.width, sizeof(myheader.width));
    out.write((char*)&myheader.height, sizeof(myheader.height));
    out.write((char*)&myheader.pathlen, sizeof(myheader.pathlen));
    out.write((char*)&myheader.desc, sizeof(myheader.desc));
    return out;
}
std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& in, header& myheader) {
    in.read((char*)&myheader.version, sizeof(myheader.version));
    in.read((char*)&myheader.width, sizeof(myheader.width));
    in.read((char*)&myheader.height, sizeof(myheader.height));
    in.read((char*)&myheader.pathlen, sizeof(myheader.pathlen));
    in.read((char*)&myheader.desc, sizeof(myheader.desc));
    return in;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << fileHeader << '\n';
    std::cin >> fileHeader;
    return 0;
}
```

Since you have no pointers, it's fairly easy!  (Note this only works with narrow streams)
Another example to show things with text, and dynamic memory/pointers/etc

```
class thing {
    std::string name;
    int height;
    friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& out, const thing & myheader);
    friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& in, thing & myheader);
public: 
    thing() {}
};

std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& out, const thing & myheader) {
    thing << name.size() << ' ';
    thing.write(&name[0], name.size()) << ' ' << height;
} 
std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& in, thing & myheader) {
    int size;
    in >> size;
    myheader.name.resize(size);
    in.read(&myheader.name[0], name.size());
    return in >> myheader.height;        
}
```

Comment: That cast could lead to trouble if the struct isn't formatted correctly.

Comment: While I appreciate your answer, I would like an explanation as to how this works. How can I be sure the data is written in the correct order (version first, than width, etc). Also, somehow that function doesn't look right to me. Something feels off.

Comment: You're (both) right, I forgot about padding.  Your struct would _not_ be 519 bytes in RAM, just on disk.  (On windows it would be 520 bytes) Fixed.  @user1019020: they would have been in order, but there would have been a nonsense byte after the version byte.

Comment: If you worry about the packing and word alignment, you're advised to call read and write on each member of the structure, not the whole thing in one go. From your Offsets, it seems you want to tightly pack the data. Your char is quite likely padded out to the short int boundary on your architecture.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, I tried your method and then reading my file back the width suddenly changed to 5192 or something, up from 20. I'll try out your new suggestion. :)

Comment: @MooingDuck IT WORKS! You are my hero! I think I understand how this works now, too. :)

Comment: Just one thing, reading actually had to be done like this. 
`char buffer[519];`
`ifs.read(buffer, 519);`
`short int width = (short int)buffer[1] | (((short int)buffer[2]) << 8);`
`short int height = (short int)buffer[3] | (((short int)buffer[4]) << 8);`

But then it works. :)

Comment: @user1019020:  Remember that the compiler is allowed to add padding between members in a class or struct.  Thus the size of a structure may not be equal to the sum of the size of its members.

Comment: @user1019020: You should not have to do that for reading.  What's wrong with the version I had?  Thomas: We already addressed that.